# why is this vanilla Js HTMLEl.style = " " not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I work in a big Vue project, I was trying to switch classes => couldn't so tried something easier ( testing purposes only) => change El style with.style.
So, the idea here is to switch the form backgroundColor when focus state is active on certain input... I was able to switch that same Input bgColor with this eventListener but never the form. Here's the code:

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent ref="formElement" class="w-full form">
    <h1
      class="mt-5 mb-3 text-2xl text-primary font-bold capitalize md:mt-0 md:mb-5 md:text-3xl"
    >
      {{ t('fullNameForm.title') }}
    </h1>
    <p class="mb-5 text-sm text-secondary md:mb-10">
      {{ t('fullNameForm.description') }}
    </p>
    <div class="flex flex-col gap-y-4">
      <Input
        id="firstName"
        autocomplete="given-name"
        :errors="v$.firstName.$errors"
        v-model.trim="v$.firstName.$model"
      >
        {{ t('firstName') }}
      </Input>
      <Input
        id="lastName"
        autocomplete="family-name"
        :errors="v$.lastName.$errors"
        v-model.trim="v$.lastName.$model"
      >
        {{ t('lastName') }}
      </Input>
    </div>
    <div
      class="w-full h-24 px-4 py-6 absolute left-0 bottom-0 sm:static sm:px-0"
    >
      <Button
        type="submit"
        :loading="loading"
        :disabled="v$.$invalid"
        class="w-full h-12 capitalize"
        @click="submit()"
      >
        {{ t('next') }}
      </Button>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref, reactive, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import useVuelidate from '@vuelidate/core'
import { required, minLength, maxLength } from '@vuelidate/validators'

import Input from '@/components/Input.vue'
import Button from '@/components/ButtonV2.vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'FullNameForm',
  components: {
    Input,
    Button
  },
  emits: ['submit'],
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const store = useStore()
    const { t } = useI18n()

    // focus events don't bubble, must use capture phase
    // document.body.addEventListener(
    //   'focus',
    //   e => {
    //     const target = e.target
    //     {
    //       document.body.classList.add('keyboard')
    //     }
    //   },
    //   true
    // )
    // document.body.addEventListener(
    //   'blur',
    //   () => {
    //     document.body.classList.remove('keyboard')
    //   },
    //   true
    // )
    const formElement = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null)
    const formEl = document.querySelector('.form') as HTMLElement | null
    onMounted(() => {
      window.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') submit()
      })
      const lastnameInput = document.querySelector(
        '#lastName'
      ) as HTMLElement | null
      if (lastnameInput || formEl) {
        lastnameInput?.addEventListener('focus', () => {
          lastnameInput.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
          if (formElement.value && formEl && lastnameInput) {
            formElement.value.style.backgroundColor = 'orange'
            formElement.value.classList.add('keyboard')
            formEl.style.backgroundColor = 'gray'
          }
        })
      }
    })

    return {
      t,
      form,
      v$,
      loading,
      submit,
      formElement
    }
  }
})
</script>

<style scoped>
.form.keyboard {
  background: rgb(81, 179, 146);
}
</style>
```

I discovered 2 things:

1. the second if never works
2. Any formEl or formElement in the first if doesn't work because it's a possible null Element, I already tried to switch operators => || to && => Nothing works, even the input stop reacting.`

Comment: vue.js !== vanilla JS. What does the consoloe of the dev tools say?

Comment: Nothing... i will try with a ref and a @focus="handleFocus" type of thing. Thank you!

Comment: @TomasGilAmoedo To make it simple, you can directly bind the class dynamically in `form` element based on the `lastName` input. `<form :class="<lastName condition> ? <if-class-name> : <else-class-name>"`